# Move Focus is not working properly on List Field

Tags: blackberry

I am working on `ListView` section, in this, the user can search the content by name and directly move at the first element of List via pressing a keyboard button. Like, if you press button B from (right vertical manager) it will scroll the list and move focus to first record of B.

[image]

The code is working fine in simulator but it's not working on Touch device - I have BB 9380 Curve.

here is the code for :

```java
LabelField a = new LabelField("A" , FOCUSABLE)
{
    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) 
    {
        graphics.setColor(0xC4C4C4);
        super.paint(graphics);
    }

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) 
    {
        //fieldChangeNotify(1);
        injectKey(Characters.LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_A);
        injectKey(Characters.LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_A);
        return true;
    }
};

private void injectKey(char key) 
{
    try 
    {
        searchList.setFocus();
        KeyEvent inject = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_DOWN, key, 0);
        inject.post();
        /*inject.post();*/

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("In injectKey :: :: :: "+e.toString());
        MessageScreen.msgDialog("In Inject Key "+e.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: I cropped your screenshot because you have included too much whitespace, and other area that just makes it harder to read your question.

Comment: hmm k..do you have any Idea about the question

Answer (score 1):

### Alternate Solution

I would recommend a different strategy for this.  Instead of trying to simulate key press events, I would define one method that handles a keypress of a certain letter, or a touch click on that same letter's `LabelField`.

[Source: blackberry.com](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29251/Implement_the_input_handling_methods_1676241_11.jsp)

So, you can have code that handles key presses by using

```java
protected boolean keyChar( char character, int status, int time ) 
{
    // you might only want to do this for the FIRST letter entered,
    //   but it sounds like you already have the keypress handling
    //   the way you want it ...
    if( CharacterUtilities.isLetter(character) )
    {
        selectLetter(character);
        return true;
    }

    return super.keyChar( character, status, time );
}
```

and then also handle touch events:

```java
LabelField a = new LabelField("A" , FOCUSABLE)
{
    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) 
    {
        graphics.setColor(0xC4C4C4);
        super.paint(graphics);
    }

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) 
    {
        char letter = getText().charAt(0);
        selectLetter(letter);
        return true;
    }
};
```

then, simply define a method that takes in one character, and scrolls to the start of that part of the list:

```java
private void selectLetter(char letter);
```

### Key Injection

If you really, really want to simulate key presses, though, you might try changing the code so that it injects two events: key down, and then key up (you're currently injecting two key down events).  This might be causing problems.

```java
    injectKey(Characters.LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_A, true);
    injectKey(Characters.LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_A, false);
```

with

```java
private void injectKey(char key, boolean down) 
{
    try 
    {
        searchList.setFocus();
        int event = down ? KeyEvent.KEY_DOWN : KeyEvent.KEY_UP;
        KeyEvent inject = new KeyEvent(event, key, 0);
        inject.post();
    } catch (Exception e) { /** code removed for clarity **/
    }
}
```

### Additional Note

For UIs, I like to trigger events on the key **up**, or **unclick** events.  I think this makes a better experience for the user.  So, you could replace `keyChar()` with `keyUp()` and `navigationClick()` with `navigationUnclick()` if you want to do this.

Comment: thanks for the response ... the scenario I observed is if touch screen device like BB 9800 bold slider is open my & you (both) code works fine but if Slider is close than it bot code doesnt work..is there any why to sort out this scenario

Comment: I don't have a 9800 slider device, so all I can test is on the 9800 simulator.  The code above worked for me, with the slider in, or out.  Perhaps you can post more information.  **What** is not working?  Please be specific.